# 3D elements buffer extrusion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, buffer, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I'm using ArcScene10.1 and I have a dataset containing of 3D points (x,y,z coordinates) with extrusion values (Evalue). Now I would like to create a square or ring buffer around the points and extrude that buffer by the extrusion value. The goal is to "layer 3D to feature class" those geometries and colour them by an other value (Cvalue). So far I was able to create a buffer around those points but I can't extrude them. 
eg.:

```
x y z Evalue Cvalue
1 2 3 5       3
2 4 1 3       15
```

...
[draft http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/741/extrudebufferdraft.jpg](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/741/extrudebufferdraft.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use [spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to join the extrusion values to your buffers.  This will make sure the buffered rings are extruded the same as the original points.

Comment: Thank you. The solution was to spatial join the datasets before creating the buffer. Than everything works out fine.